# Actionbar Menu Items executing wrong code based on its Menu Id

Tags: android, android-actionbar, clipboard, menuitem

Im having an issue with my Menu Items in my actionbar executing the wrong code based on its Menu ID.

### Current Code

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem Item) {

        switch (Item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.menu_back:
            web.goBack();
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_forward:
            web.goForward();
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_refresh:
            web.reload();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(Item);
 }
```

Example:  `menu_back` - Would execute the code for `menu_forward` and `menu_forward` would execute the code for `menu_refresh`  etc.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by the MenuItem named `Item` within the above `onOptionsItemSelected` code. If for some reason Eclipse prompted me that this need an Import and if your like me, you when you need to add an Import you simply execute Ctrl O to import all the required Imports.

So Eclipse imported `android.content.ClipData.Item`. Which then caused all my Menu Items to execute the incorrect code and wasn't referencing the proper `Case R.id.menu_item` in order to run the proper code.

I don't understand really why this prompted the Import in the first place, however i caught it and was able to resolve it by simply Removing the Import statement or if you need the import, just change the `MenuItem` name from `Item` to `item` or whatever name you want to use.

### Working Code

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.menu_back:
            web.goBack();
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_forward:
            web.goForward();
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_refresh:
            web.reload();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
```

Just wanted share my experience with this issue and help someone else out that may run into this.